# How to sort a list and handle None values properly?

Tags: python

I am trying to sort a list of objects using the date attribute with

```py
list_of_objects.sort(key=lambda x: x.date, reverse=True)
```

but some dates are just `None`, which means that I get the error

```
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to NoneType
```

is there a way to account for this? e.g. Have objects with `date == None` at the top or bottom of the sorted list—or do I need to do this manually?

Comment: if is null x.date return default date, today for example

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can modify your lambda slightly:

```
from datetime import datetime

list_of_objects.sort(key=lambda x: x.date or datetime.min, reverse=True)
```

If they're appearing at the wrong end of the sort, use `datetime.max` instead.

Answer (score 35):

You want to sort based on two properties:

1. Primarily, whether a date is present
2. Secondarily, the date (if present)

You can express your intent in a straightforward manner by sorting on a tuple, where

1. the first element of the tuple specifies whether the date is `None`, and
2. the second element of the tuple is the date itself.

```
list_of_objects.sort(key=lambda x: (x.date is None, x.date), reverse=True)
```

This approach circumvents the type error that you are getting, because comparison between tuples is performed left-to-right lazily. The second tuple elements don't get compared unless the first elements are equal.

Here are some examples demonstrating the concept:

```
>>> xs = [None, 1, 3, None, 2]

>>> sorted(xs, key=lambda x: (x is None, x))
[1, 2, 3, None, None]

>>> sorted(xs, key=lambda x: (x is not None, x))
[None, None, 1, 2, 3]

>>> sorted(xs, key=lambda x: (x is None, x), reverse=True)
[None, None, 3, 2, 1]

>>> sorted(xs, key=lambda x: (x is not None, x), reverse=True)
[3, 2, 1, None, None]
```

Comment: This explanation just helped me to solve a bug. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should filter out the dates that are None first, before sorting.

Comment: Maybe an example of the approach would be useful.. Look at the answer from @wim for an example. Give a solution, not just a suggestion. peace